# Which layer should (In app purchase), (Firebase Messaging) go in? Data or Presentation layer?

Tags: flutter, clean-architecture

Hi : ) I am a flutter developer.

In Clean Archtecture the idea of layered architecture, and in particular that the business logic should be confined to domain layer and separated from UI/persistence/other concerns.

To me the following left unclear:

Which layer should  (In app purchase), (Firebase Messaging) go in? Data or Presentation layer?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9PiV.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In clean architecture, you have 4 layers (from the inside to the outside) :

- Entreprise Business Rules
- Application Business Rules
- Interface Adapters
- Frameworks & Drivers

The "Framworks & Drivers" layer contains Devices, DB, External Interfaces, UI, Web...

Firebase Messaging should be in the most outside layer.

Comment: Yep !!Thanks man

Comment: If my answer suits you, don't forget to validate my answer :-)